# Работа с Chart-ом. Нужно нарисовать что-то похожее на StepLine

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

Подскажите как сделать диаграмму как на примере (снизу справа) из красных линий?
Очень похоже на степлайн но, мне не нужно соединять точки 2-3
нужны соединения 1-2 3-4 и т.д
Единственное что имею как вариант, это создание для каждой линии нового элемента Series. 
Но мне как раз и не хочется создавать элемент каждый раз.
И скажите насколько этот вариант тяжел по выч. мощности по сравнению с тем что я хочу?
Картинку прилагаю (последняя темная линия тоже должна быть красной, в пеинте затупил)

[image: Мне нужна диаграмма из красных линий]

Comment: Вам обязательно стандартный Chart использовать?

Comment: Желательно. Вы можете что-то предложить?.
И другой вопрос: а можно, например, скрыть колонку и отобразить только ее верхнюю границу?

Comment: https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Step%20Line

Comment: касательно второго вопроса, то попробуйте установить `Background=Transparent`

Comment: @Ev_Hyper спасибо, что напомнили про прозрачный цвет. Сделал так: поставил прозрачный, установил на фон картинку (в пеинте нарисовал линию) и закрепил вверху. В качестве кастыля пойдет (есть небольшое смещение вниз относительно нужного значения, потому что картинка вставляется во внутрь столбца, а не на границу + не удается сделать повторение по х, если растягиваю окно меняется и область chart - а и когда ширины картинки уже не хватает, естественно, образуется незаполненное пространство). А со смещением вниз не знаю как побороться,поскольку оно не константно, чтобы просто добавить немного по у